# Button doesn't receive mouse click when placed over DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, buttonclick

I try to use a Button to load file name and path into DataGridView cell.
I place the button on a cell like this:

```
var cellRectangle = dataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false);
int buttonX = dataGridView.Location.X + cellRectangle.Location.X + cellRectangle.Width - btnLoadFile.Width;
int buttonY = dataGridView.Location.Y + cellRectangle.Location.Y;

btnLoadFile.Location = new Point(buttonX + 20, buttonY);
btnLoadFile.Height = cellRectangle.Height - 2;
btnLoadFile.Visible = true;
btnLoadFile.BringToFront();
```

I would like the user to click the button, choose file in FileDialog etc.
The problem is the button doesn't get clicked. The grid cell receives the clicks instead.

Does anyone have an idea why it happens and how can I handle it?

Comment: make the button as child of datagrid view else reroute the buttons click event

Comment: @Uthistran : just tried it. The button still doesn't respond to clicks....

Comment: This sounds wrong. You probably just didn't hook it up right. If you can see and and click it it __will__ call its click event. What happens when you doubleclick it in the designer?

Comment: @TaW :  Yes, it looks wrong too. The button is seen on top of the grid. If I click it the button doesn't change its appearance, instead the cell underneath the button receives focus as if I clicked on the cell and not on the button.  There is event procedure linked to the button of course.

Comment: How is the button added? in the designer? in code? any code that modifies the button in any way? can you remove it and re-add that button? is it added to the form or to the dgv.Controls? - also:clean and re-build!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
dataGridView.Controls.SetChildIndex(btnLoadFile, 0);
// Bring it to the front
btnLoadFile.BringToFront();
```

Maybe you don't need the last line ...

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't change anything... Same behavior as before

Answer (score 0):

I would use DataGridViewButtonColumn instead of drawing a button above the grid.
That gives you a button inside each row.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to have the button inside another cell that displays for example emails, you could derive the desired editcell type and implement a combination of TextBox and Button and make the button only visible when in editmode. Look here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.100).aspx
for more info. I would post you some Code but unfortunatly I only made my own cells/editcontrols for different purposes.

Comment: Yes, I know about this option but just to throw a button on the form and place it on a cell seemed to be much simpler. Also I wouldn't like the whole column filled with buttons, it's not informative for the user just clutter